# Extracting ip address from auth.log line to a variable

Tags: regex, bash

I am going nuts here already, but I need to extract ip address from such line:

"Jan 15 14:05:57 seerrrver sshd[9784]: User root from 218.108.249.44 not allowed because not listed in AllowUsers"

I think, it should be something like this:
address=$(expr match "$line" '\b[[:digit:]]{1,3}.[[:digit:]]{1,3}.[[:digit:]]{1,3}.[[:digit:]]{1,3}\b')

But actually these regular expressions doesnt work with expr match command. I have tried this match with other command and it works, the only place, where it doesnt work, is the expr match command.

Comment: so, use "other" command?

Answer (score 3):

Grep is made for cases like this.

```
address=$(echo "Jan 15 14:05:57 seerrrver sshd[9784]: User root from 218.108.249.44 not allowed because not listed in AllowUsers" | grep -Eo '([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}')
```

`echo $address` returns the IP address.

Assuming you have a full log file, it makes sense to process all rows at once and put the output in an array:

```
addressarray=( $(cat logfile | grep -Eo '([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}' |  sed -n -e ":a" -e "$ s/\n/ /gp;N;b a") )
```

You can look at the contents of the array using `echo ${addressarray[@]}` or access its values by replacing the @ with an index number (starting with 0). `echo ${addressarray[0]}` would give you the first address.

Use this to iterate over the array values:
`for i in ${!addressarray[@]}; do echo ${addressarray[$i]}; done`

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use `expr` since Bash 3.2 and later have regex matching.

```
string="Jan 15 14:05:57 seerrrver sshd[9784]: User root from 218.108.249.44 not allowed because not listed in AllowUsers"
pattern='\<([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\>'
[[ $string =~ $pattern ]]
address=${BASH_REMATCH[0]}
```

The regex support provided by `expr` is very limited (it only does basic regular expressions - BRE) rather than extended ones (ERE)).